# CSS/SCSS changes to code not applying in browser

Tags: html, css, django, styles, scss-mixins

I am trying to hide a number by modifying the scss/css. It is the tag in the picture: poll-row__number.

[image: Screenshot inspector]
Strange thing is also it is not in the scss file the inspector is showing but another.

I am running an Adhocracy installation (Nginx on Ubuntu Linux) in a virtual environment. I changed all the poll-row__number references in css/ scss files to display:none / visibility:hidden. Rebooted the server and deleted my cache from my browser, tried Chrome, FireFox and Safari. But the number stays visible. When I change it in the inspector, it dissapears.

This is my css directory with files [image: css with directories]
The poll-row__number is in _poll.scss like here [image: Tag in my scss]
As you can see the value display:none/ visibility:hidden is added.

When grepping the div it finds nothing systemwide. When grepping the pol-row__number it finds it, but everything it finds is changed to display:none/ visibility:hidden.

What am I doing wrong and what else do you want for information to help me fix this strange ptoblem.

I tried all I can think of.

Comment: Please post code itself, not screenshots of code.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much of code you're showing us. So it'll be hard to find the error.

- Try to add `display: none;` in the console (web browser)
- First make sure the scss is translated to the css file :

sass --watch src/scss/_project_header.scss:src/css/_project_header.css

- Second, verify that the `.poll-row__number` is not used in another `css` file linked to you `html` file because as we can see the current `display` is `inline-block`.
- Then, check if you don't use twice `.poll-row__number` because the basic css rule is the following, the last property stated is the one that overlaps the others, example :

CSS

```
.poll-row__number{
display :none;
}

.poll-row__number{
display :inline-block;
}
```

There, `.poll-row__number` will get `inline-block`. And I just saw that you have this issue in your code (or was it on purpose) :

Line 1 : `.poll-row__number` (has no display property)
Line 2 : `.poll-row__number, .poll-row__label` (has display inline-block)

(It is my opinion but using "__" for ids or class is ugly and confusing. Please stop it: either use "CamelCase" or just use one "_")

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am sorry if I did not provide enough information. I can add any code snippets you want, but I am not sure which code would contribute to a possible solution.

When I try to display: none in the console, it works.
I will edit the scss/ css files and post them. Also the grep command so it is clear I searched the entire system for .poll-row__number and that I didn't miss any files.
I will try sass --watch src/scss/_project_header.scss:src/css/_project_header.css and come back with the results.

Comment: I do not have the sass command installed. And thanks for the feedback about the double underscores. I agree.

Comment: You can install sass : https://sass-lang.com/install . The commands are : brew install sass/sass/sass (linux/mac) or choco install sass (if you use chocholatey) or npm install -g sass (if you use Node.js)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help. I found the solution. Maybe obvious for a lot of developers, but I am not a pro in this sence.

What I did:

I changed the css/scss files that I wanted to change.
Then I went to my virtual environment and did:

```
npm install npm run build:prod
pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=adhocracy-plus.config.settings.build
python manage.py compilemessages
python manage.py collectstatic
```

I do not know if they all are needed, but I figured, maybe the css/scss is build and stored somewhere and then called so it overrides the css file in the projectfolder.
After this I restarted my processes:

```
sudo systemctl

restart Adhocracy-plus

sudo systemctl restart Adhocracy-plus.service

sudo systemctl restart Adhocracy-plus-background-task

sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Then it worked.

In conclusion:

CSS/SCSS is compiled. So changed the CSS/SCSS, recompiled/ build the project ,restarted the services.